# List of Pointers

Tags: dart

I want to do something similar with list of pointers

Does anyone have an example?

```
List<Map> listOfMaps = [{"name":"Map1"},{"name":"Map2"}];

List<Point> listofPointers = [........];
```

thank you

Comment: please rephrase this question with more detail about what you are trying to do.

Comment: ok, i will try to explain it.
i want to use a lot of Point(x,y) and want to store them inside of a List.
I need a way to fill them quick without a lot of
    

    List.add new Point[x,y];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you want something like

```dart
List<Point>  points = [
                       new Point(10,10), 
                       new Point(20,20) ];
```

Answer (score 0):

ok, thank you

i wrote this:

```
List<Point> MatrixofPointer = new List<Point>(8);

  MatrixofPointer[0] = new Point(-1,-1);
  MatrixofPointer[1] = new Point( 0,-1);
  MatrixofPointer[2] = new Point( 1,-1);
  MatrixofPointer[3] = new Point(-1, 0);
  MatrixofPointer[4] = new Point( 1, 0);
  MatrixofPointer[5] = new Point(-1, 1);
  MatrixofPointer[6] = new Point( 1, 0);
  MatrixofPointer[7] = new Point( 1, 1);
```

but a short version would be nice